# Click button show iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I need help with using an iframe. I want to make it so that if someone clicks on a button then they see my widget `<iframe src="domain.com" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 250px;"></iframe>`

[image]

Now I use

```
<form name="form_reg_full" id="form_reg_full" class="clearfix" method="post" action="domain.com">
```

But it only redirects to domain.com and it doesn't show my widget

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific.Are you using pure javascript, jquery, angular, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you've said this code would be ok for you:

**Javascrpit**

```
function show_frame(state)
{
    document.getElementById("myiframe").style.display = state;
}
```

**Html**

```
<input type="button" onclick="show_frame('block');" value=" show frame" /> 
<iframe id="myiframe" style="border: 0; width: 100%;
 height:250px;display:none; width: 1020px; height: 320px" src="domain.com">
</iframe>
```